# Finding the average of the three smallest values in range - Unexpected Compile Error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find the average value of the three smallest values in a range. To do so, I am combining the Average and Small function as seen below.

I've based my attempt on the 4th reply on this oz forum post, (https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/13081-searching-range-for-lowest-three-values), but keep getting a compile error that highlights the ":" between A2 and A10 where I'm defining my range.

```
dim threeminavr AS single

threeminavr = WorksheetFunction.Average(Small(A2:A10,1), Small(A2:A10,2), Small(A2:A10,3))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use SMALL like it was on the worksheet when it is used as a worksheetfunction function.

```
threeminavr = WorksheetFunction.Average(WorksheetFunction.Small(range("A2:A10"), 1), _
                                        WorksheetFunction.Small(range("A2:A10"), 2), _
                                        WorksheetFunction.Small(range("A2:A10"), 3))
```

Comment: Opps! Thanks for the response. Worked as desired.